# Query including NULL and '' in SUM values even though it should be explicitly excluding them

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark-sql

This query is taking parsed http requests and created counts of how many times certain types of page elements were viewed, then grouping by a number of criteria.  It should be explicitly excluding records from being counted in the `SUM` functions if the `controller_context_id` doesn't have some value other than `NULL` or `''`.  After running the query, however, I still get rows with an unpopulated `controller_context_id` that contains summed up numbers for whatever the `controller_type` was.  This shouldn't happen.  I would expect any rows that don't have a `controller_context_id` to have 0 in all the `num_page_views_*` columns.

Have I missed something fundamental in the logic of my query?

```
SELECT
            TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month') AS request_timestamp,
            account_id,
            account_guid,
            cluster_id,
            shard_id,
            unique_id,
            context_id,
            controller_type,
            controller_context_id,
            concat_user_id,
            user_id,
            COUNT(account_id) AS num_page_views,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'pages%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_pages,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'files%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_files,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'modules%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_modules,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'assignments%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_assignments,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'quizzes%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_quizzes,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'discussion_topics%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_discussion_topics,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'outcome%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_outcomes,
            COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS num_sessions
        FROM requests
        GROUP BY
          TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month'),
          account_id,
          account_guid,
          cluster_id,
          shard_id,
          unique_id,
          context_id,
          context_id,
          controller_type,
          controller_context_id,
          concat_user_id,
          user_id
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a clear flaw in your query (other than that you group by `context_id` twice, which oughtn't to actually change anything).  Is it possible that you are being fooled by values of `controller_context_id` that consist of one or more blanks?  You would definitely have that rather than empty strings if the type of `controller_context_id` were `CHAR(n)` as opposed to `VARCHAR(n)`, but you could have it with `VARCHAR(n)` as well.

Comment: But since you're grouping by `controller_context_id` anyway, why does it matter?  The unwanted statistics do not contaminate your other statistics.

Comment: I think the analyst is then doing a sum of all values in the various `num_page_views` columns for a dashboard, so it's giving us incorrect results

Comment: The basics defining your question are missing: table definition and Postgres version.